# Creating a table with data from 2 other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am working in access and utilizing VBA to make queries in wich I have variable names, so I can't use the query wizard in access

I have the following 2 tables:

```
tblKabelInfo
```

And a table with a name that varies depending on something else in my program

```
tblName1 as String
```

the tables look like this:

```
tblKabelInfo:

+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Kabelnummer  |   data   |more data |even more |           
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+

tblName1:

+--------------------------------+----------+----------+
| Filename                       |   bla    | databla  |
+--------------------------------+---------------------+
|\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0001.SOR |    x     |    x     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+
|\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0002.SOR |    x     |    x     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+
|\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0003.SOR |    x     |    x     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+
|\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0004.SOR |    x     |    x     |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+
```

I know that both tables are of the same size (so if the table "tblName1" goes up to 0234.SOR, I know that Kabelnummer from "tblKabelInfo" also goes up to 234)

I would like to make a query that makes a new table that looks something like this:

```
NewTable:

+--------------------------------+--------------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+
| Filename                       |KabelNummer   | bla |databla | More Data |Even more|
+--------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0001.SOR | 1            |  x  |   x    |     x     |    x    |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+
|\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0002.SOR | 2            |  x  |   x    |     x     |    x    |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+
|\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0003.SOR | 3            |  x  |   x    |     x     |    x    |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+
|\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0004.SOR | 4            |  x  |   x    |     x     |    x    |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+
```

I would like to have the 2 tables in 1 table and the common factor is that the end of "Filename" should be the same as "KabelNummer"

Comment: instead of `@products` use `B.FileName`. Also you misse `AS INT)` at the end

Comment: am updated my answer with the corrected query. Have a look

Comment: `CAST` and `SUBSTRING` are not Access SQL functions.

Comment: @HansUp Then how should I formulate this query in Access VBA SQL?

Comment: Use Access SQL functions: `Val()`; `Mid()`; and `InStr()`.

Comment: @HansUp Care to show in an answer how I should do that? I have read up on the functions but am still a bit confused as to how I can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the basic challenge here is to identify the digits in `tblName1.Filename` which can then be used to join with `tblKabelInfo.Kabelnummer`.

If those digits are always the first 4 of the last 8 characters of the string, you can use `Right` and `Left`, which are compatible with Access SQL, to get them easily.

Here is a session from the Immediate window.

```vb
Filename = "\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0001.SOR"
? Right(Filename, 8)
0001.SOR
? Left(Right(Filename, 8), 4)
0001
```

If you need to convert those characters to a numeric value, you can use the `Val` function.

```vb
? Val(Left(Right(Filename, 8), 4))
 1
```

However, if the `Filename` values are more variable, not always ending with a period and 3 more characters, the task will be more challenging.

```vb
Filename = "\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0001.ABCDEF"
? InstrRev(Filename, "_")
 23 
? InstrRev(Filename, ".")
 28 
? Mid(Filename, InstrRev(Filename, "_") + 1, _
    (InstrRev(Filename, ".") - InstrRev(Filename, "_")) - 1)
0001
? Val(Mid(Filename, InstrRev(Filename, "_") + 1, _
    (InstrRev(Filename, ".") - InstrRev(Filename, "_")) - 1))
 1
```

Once you work out the appropriate mix of functions to get what you need, you can use them in your Access query.  Here is a query using both of those approaches.   It runs without error in Access 2007 with your sample data in *tblName1*.

```sql
SELECT
    t.Filename,
    Val(Left(Right(Filename, 8), 4)) AS Kabelnummer1,
    Val(
            Mid(
                Filename,
                InstrRev(Filename, "_") + 1,
                (InstrRev(Filename, ".") - InstrRev(Filename, "_")) - 1
            )
        ) AS Kabelnummer2
FROM tblName1 AS t;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Already had something like this, but chosen as answer for future reference and people having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this

```
INSERT INTO tableNew
SELECT B.Filename,
       A.Kabelnummer,
       B.bla,
       B.databla,
       A.data,
       A.[more data],
       A.[even more]
FROM tblKabelInfo A INNER JOIN tblName1  B
ON A.Kabelnummer=CAST(RIGHT(SUBSTRING( B.Filename,1,LEN(SUBSTRING( B.Filename, 0, PATINDEX('%.%', B.Filename)) + '.') - 1),4)
```

Updated to handle upto your 4 digit in filename. `0001` to `9999`

**Your Query (EDIT)**

```
INSERT INTO tableNew
SELECT B.[Filename],
   A.[Vezelnummer],
   B.[tblVerlies1_Verlies],
   B.[tblVerlies2_Verlies],
   A.[KabelNaam],
   A.[Van],
   A.[Naar],
   A.[VezelLengte],
   A.[TypeKabel],
   A.[TypeConnector],
   A.[AantalConnectoren],
   A.[AantalLassen]
 FROM tblKabelInfo A INNER JOIN tbl_GL_850  B
ON A.Vezelnummer=CAST(RIGHT(SUBSTRING(B.[Filename],1,LEN(SUBSTRING(B.[Filename], 0, PATINDEX('%.%',B.[Filename])) + '.') - 1),4) AS INT)
```

Comment: updated to handle upto your 4 digit in filename. `0001` to `9999`

Comment: It tells me there is a syntax error in `A.Kabelnummer=CAST(SUBSTRING(B.Filename, LEN(SUBSTRING(B.Filename, 0, PATINDEX('%.%',B.Filename)) + '.') - 1, 1) AS INT)`

Comment: Is it possible to use a * ? to select all columns at once

Comment: @Niyhesh It tells me theres a missing ), ] or element in the query

Comment: yes you can. But better to specify column names for better performance and also safe.

Comment: `DECLARE @products varchar(200) = '\850\850nm_Lessenaar 1_0001.SOR'
SELECT 1
WHERE CAST(RIGHT(SUBSTRING(@products,1,LEN(SUBSTRING(@products, 0, PATINDEX('%.%',@products)) + '.') - 1),4) AS INT)=1` Try this query. this will give you an idea about what i am did.

Comment: @Nitesh I have edited my question to show you what I have done so far

Comment: intead of @Product use `B.FileName`

Comment: @Nitesh all three of them? gives me the same error. Also the same error when I use the new query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.Filename,T.bla,T.databla,K.MoreData,K.EvenMore
INTO 
[New Table Name]
FROM tblName1 as T
inner join tblKabelInfo as K
ON CAST(SUBSTRING(T.Filename,[length of filename upto number],1)AS INT)= K.KabelNummer;
```

Havent tested but will be something along these lines, i recommend looking up `select into` you could start [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp).